# FTP upload a list of files saved in a txt preserving the path in the server side?

Tags: batch, ftp, automation, upload

I have a list of files changes, example:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/index.php
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/css/styles.css
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/css/styles001.css
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/system/model/core.php
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/system/controllers/admin/users.php
```

How can I do to upload them in one shot via FTP using Linux?

Answer (score 3):

You can find an example of how to do this [here](http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/ftp/ftp_script_linux.htm).

From the page itself:

```
## upload the files
INPUT=/path/to/list_of_files_to_upload
LOCALBASE=/home/pete/website        #local directory that corresponds to the root of the website

for ITEM in $(cat $INPUT); do
      FILE=$(basename $ITEM)
      LOCALDIR=$(dirname $ITEM)

      if  [ "$LOCALDIR" == "$LOCALBASE" ]; then
                REMOTEDIR="/"
      else
              REMOTEDIR=${LOCALDIR#$LOCALBASE}
      fi

  ## ftp starts here
  ftp -v -n $SERVER <<END_OF_SESSION
  user $USER $PASSW
  $FILETYPE
  lcd $LOCALDIR
  cd $REMOTEDIR
  put $FILE
  bye
  END_OF_SESSION
done
```